# Oozie - workflow.xml in YARN

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie

In oozie when we schedule map-reduce jobs in YARN cluster we still use task tracker tag.

But in practical there is no tasktracker in YARN, we will have resource manager.

why is oozie still having job-tracker tag ? Is there any reason for that.

```
<job-tracker>[JOB-TRACKER]</job-tracker>
<name-node>[NAME-NODE]</name-node>
```